# proxy parameters with nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm trying to use nginx to proxy a request with parameters to a shoutcast stream. I've tried a couple things but can't seem to get it working right. First try was this

```
location /music/ {
     proxy_pass http://dest.server.net/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

That resulted in the following log:

2015/02/25 17:37:32 [error] 12183#0: *1 no resolver defined to resolve dest.server.net, client: 1.2.3.4, server: myserver.org, request: "GET /full/path/1/foo/bar.pls?p1=1&p2=2 HTTP/1.1", host: "myserver.org"

When I add a resolver:

```
location /music/ {
 resolver 8.8.8.8;
 proxy_pass http://dest.server.net/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

It seems to not try to proxy the request at all:

2015/02/25 17:42:34 [error] 12106#0: *3 open() "/full/path/1/foo/bar.pls" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 1.2.3.4, server: myserver.org, request: "GET /full/path/1/foo/bar.pls?p1=1&p2=2 HTTP/1.1", host: "myserver.org"

If it needs to be accessed on my server with full path/parameters that would work, just need to pass those off to the real server.

Any suggestions on making this work?

Comment: You have `/music/` location, but `/full/path/1/...` in logs. Please, if you try to hide real URIs do this consistently.

Comment: BTW, this error means, nginx tries to open file from disk, not proxy it

Comment: Also, where does `$1` come from ? It's probably an empty string considering excerpts you gave us. Post the whole configuration file.